# Rails - embedded if statement, unexpected result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an unexpected result from an if statement in my Article controller. My intention is to allow the article author or an admin user (it's a boolean column in the users table) to update an article. I want to check if the current user was the original author, and if so, update the author name, just in case the person has changed their username after the article was posted.

The problem is that when an admin updates the article, its not only changing the author name to admin, its also setting the user_id to admin! I don't understand why. The admin.id does not match the article.user_id, so why is this happening?

Here's the bit from the article controller:

```
def update
@article = Article.find(params[:id])

if @article.user_id == current_user.id || current_user.admin?
  #update author in case of user name change
    if @article.user_id = current_user.id
      @article.author = current_user.name
    end 
  if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
else
    render 'edit'
end

elsif
  redirect_to articles_path, :notice => "You do not have permission to edit this resource."
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if @article.user_id = current_user.id`

this is an assignment (and always true)

it needs to be `if @article.user_id == current_user.id`

Comment: Thank you Phil! I've been sitting in front of the computer too long. Can't believe I didn't spot that.